# What shall I do if someone pushed new commits to master of git repository after I merged my work to master but didn't push?

Tags: git, merge

I'm just starting using GIT. Consider a very small team with only 2 developers: devA and devB.

Here is the scenario:

1. They are all working based on commit ver-01.
2. DevA committed ver-02 and pushed to the central repo.
3. DevB push his/her ver-03 but failed, so devB fetched the master and now has a master which contains ver-03 and origin/master which contains ver02. He/she merged master with origin/master and now has ver-04 which contain both ver-02 and ver-03, and then push it to central repository normally.

What I want to know is, when DevB is merging the code, DevA pushed another ver-05. So after DevB merged his/her master with origin/master, he/she still cannot push, for he/she have to resolve the conflict between ver-04 and ver-05. If I'm DevB, I ran 'git fetch origin master', but what command shall I run to merge? I tried 'git merge origin master' but it tells me 'Already up-to-date.', but when I push it failed.

I found that there are actually 3 branches:

- master --> contains my change, which is ver-03
- origin/master --> contains the latest remote change, which is ver-05
- HEAD -> origin/master --> contains the ver-04, which is merged from ver-02 and ver-03.

What shall I do next?

Comment: Try `git merge` or `git fetch`  or `git pull`

Comment: I'd certainly recommend you backup your work before you do anything!

Comment: `git pull origin master`, fix conflicts if occurs (then do commit), `git push origin master`

Comment: The short answer is: you must re-merge, possibly after discarding your existing merge, or re-base (which also discards existing merges). You need to read a good book on Git.

Answer (score 0):

First I would back-up my work with:
git checkout -b backup

Move back to master:
git checkout master

Pull from remote and resolve conflicts:
git pull

Push changes:
git push

I would strongly advise you to work on branches (and avoid pushing straight to master like this):

git checkout -b feature (creates new branch and does a checkout on it)
git push -u origin feature (pushes branch to remote)
git commit -am "Commit1"

Now you have two options (you are on feature branch):
git rebase master (if you are working alone on this branch)
or
git merge master (if other people use the branch as well)

Resolve conflicts

git checkout master (move to master)

git merge feature (merge your branch into master)

git push

---

If you made a small change to master you can:

git stash (saves your work in a stash)

git pull (brings remote changes to local)

git stash apply (applies your changes on top of remote changes)

Resolve conflicts

git commit -m "Message"

git push